# Editable dropdown in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

There is a requirement, where it is asked to make the dropdown box editable in TinyMCE........

[image]

Can it be converted in editable select box such as in libre and MS office product

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopfully, i am able to achieve the result by using `combobox` as the type in my custom button.

```
setup: function (editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', function() {
           var items= ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28", "36", "48", "72"]
           return {
                  type: 'combobox',
                  autofocus: true,
                  label: 'FontSizes',
                  values: items,
                  onChange: function(e){
                        console.log(this.value());
                  }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
editor.addButton('mybutton', {
    type: 'combobox',
    icon: false,
    text: 'FontSizes',
    values: [{text: "8", value:"8"}, {text: "9", value:"9"}, {text: "10", value:"10"}, {text: "12", value:"12"}, {text: "14", value:"14"}, {text: "16", value:"16"}, {text: "18", value:"18"}],
    onselect: function(e){
        console.log(this.value());
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/grajsek/pen/QKmzGv)

**EDIT**: added demo